# How do you get and set keys using Google Cloud MemCache (node js)?

Tags: node.js, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

I'm using node.js and google app engine. My understanding is that memcache is some shared memory where you can store keys.

docs: https://cloud.google.com/nodejs/docs/reference/memcache/latest

The docs say, install the memcache api:

```
npm install "@google-cloud/memcache".
```

And then get a memcache instance like this:

```
const {CloudMemcacheClient} = require('@google-cloud/memcache');

// Creates a client
const cmc = new CloudMemcacheClient();
```

But then what?

How do I get and set keys? The documentation just seems to end.

Hope some kind person knows how this is supposed to work.

Comment: Accessing memorystore/redis from GAE is more complicated than that.  See here: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/nodejs/using-memorystore.  Memcache is only for older GAE that is now deprecated.

Comment: Ah, thanks @gaefan I'll checked the newer recommended stuff.